# HIVE Pivot and count

Tags: hive, count, pivot, transpose

I have a table that I am trying to figure out how to pivot and count based on these.
This example may not be very suitable, but the result is exactly what I want.

Example input:

```
name |chinese|math|english
tom  |A      |A   |B
tom  |B      |A   |C
peter|B      |C   |C
peter|A      |B   |C
```

Example output:

```
name |object |A|B|C
tom  |chinese|1|1|0
tom  |math   |2|0|0
tom  |english|0|1|1
peter|chinese|1|1|0
peter|math   |0|1|1
peter|english|0|0|2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL with aggregation.

Demo:

```
with your_table as (
select stack(4,
'tom'  ,'A','A','B',
'tom'  ,'B','A','C',
'peter','B','C','C',
'peter','A','B','C'
) as (name,chinese,math,english)
)

select name, 'chinese' as object, 
       count(case when chinese='A' then 1 end) as A, 
       count(case when chinese='B' then 1 end) as B,
       count(case when chinese='C' then 1 end) as C
  from your_table 
 group by name
    UNION ALL 
select name, 'math' as object, 
       count(case when math='A' then 1 end) as A, 
       count(case when math='B' then 1 end) as B,
       count(case when math='C' then 1 end) as C
  from your_table 
 group by name
    UNION ALL 
select name, 'english' as object, 
       count(case when english='A' then 1 end) as A, 
       count(case when english='B' then 1 end) as B,
       count(case when english='C' then 1 end) as C
  from your_table 
 group by name;
```

Result:

```
name    object  a       b       c
peter   chinese 1       1       0
tom     chinese 1       1       0
peter   math    0       1       1
tom     math    2       0       0
peter   english 0       0       2
tom     english 0       1       1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is worked.but I want to use other way like str_to_map,collect_list this kind,How can I do it?

Comment: @cheryH For this task you do not need str_to_map, nor collect_list